# MySQL server app runs, but MySQL Server doesn't load

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am running a Mac OS 10.12.3 and have downloaded the Mysql Server (which runs by clicking "start Mysql server" button), the green light comes on to indicate its running. But when I go over to add a MySQL workbench and try to "set up a new connection" with the following credentials:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COtC7.jpg)

I get an error message saying:
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have gone to terminal and typed in "mysql" and get the same kind of error. 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'leobalboni'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What am I doing wrong? I want to run the server and upload a database so I can do some exercises. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: did you actually enter a password in mysql workbench? The error message suggests that you did - but did you? In any case try the command line with full credentials: `mysql -u root -ppasswordyesitsattached mysql`

Comment: Hi, yes I did. I put in the one that I use to log on to my mac (presuming that is the universal pw). I just copied your script into my terminal and gave me the following error again:

Comment: I stopped the server app and tried it again, then gave me this error. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: if you copied my script, did you replace the password part with your password though? Sorry for asking...

Comment: No, thats quite all right. I´m a newby and sometimes we can make mistakes like that. Yes, i did replace the password part with my password: mysql -u root -pmypassword mysql and got the following error: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I think it's normal then. The root password IIRC is not initialized anymore in newer mysql versions. Try following the command line instructions of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html, section "B.5.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions". I think it should do it.

Comment: Hi Sebas, thanks for your information. I have managed to reset the password from root. But still gives me the same error: Leonardos-iMac:~ root# sudo passwd root
Changing password for root.
New password:
Retype new password:
Leonardos-iMac:~ root# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Sebas!!!! I found the solution. Thanks for your help. I uninstalled the server and the workbench. Reinstalled both of them, this time i wrote down the temp password they give you when setting it up, when I connected I pasted it in then changed to a new password. It is all running now. It seems thought from the command line I can't reset it, whether its from root or my account. Cheers for your help Happy days!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fresh install, try reinstalling. 
The last time i encountered this problem was because of a missing file/configuration.

Comment: Kostas, thanks for your help too. Seems that uninstalling it and reinstalling it was the case, but not like yours. I copied down the temp password, used that and then it asked me for a new password when I logged on to the connection. So all good. Thanks anyway.